# Wordpress Woocommerce product is being added to cart on page refresh

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem using woocommerce.

After I add a product to cart the link in browser becomes **link/?add-to-cart=72**,and if i refresh the page the product is added again in cart.

Every refresh addes the product in cart.
I disabled all plugins except woocommerce and still the same.

Any ideea on how to fix this ?Thank You.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same issue once, here is the code that you should add to your theme’s `functions.php` file, or to your own custom plugin:

```
add_action('add_to_cart_redirect', 'cipher_add_to_cart_redirect');
 
function cipher_add_to_cart_redirect($url = false) {
 
     // If another plugin beats us to the punch, let them have their way with the URL
     if(!empty($url)) { return $url; }
 
     // Redirect back to the original page, without the 'add-to-cart' parameter.
     // We add the `get_bloginfo` part so it saves a redirect on https:// sites.
     return get_bloginfo('wpurl').add_query_arg(array(), remove_query_arg('add-to-cart'));
 
}
```

It will add a redirection when users added products to their cart. I hope this helps.

Comment: This helped me as well, but If you use a custom folder you have to change `get_bloginfo('wpurl')` to `get_bloginfo('url')`

Comment: Confirmed this fix still works in 2021 on Woocommerce Version 1.15.1. Thank you!

Comment: Nice and simple, thanks for the fix

Comment: My pleasure :) ..

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer @asfandyar-khan, it works for me.

Just a little update though, add_to_cart_redirect is deprecated since version 3.0.0, we need to use woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect instead.

Which makes :

```php
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'example_add_to_cart_redirect');

function example_add_to_cart_redirect($url = false) {
 
     // If another plugin beats us to the punch, let them have their way with the URL
     if(!empty($url)) { return $url; }
 
     // Redirect back to the original page, without the 'add-to-cart' parameter.
     // We add the `get_bloginfo` part so it saves a redirect on https:// sites.
     return get_bloginfo('wpurl').add_query_arg(array(), remove_query_arg('add-to-cart'));
 
}
```